# Reportviewer with vb.net 2016 and MSAccess

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ms-access-2016

I am doing a project for class. I am using reportviewer to pull data from a dataconnection named fitnesscompanydb.accdb . It keeps throwing this error now.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

```
Public Class frmSignupReportQuery
Private Sub frmSignupReportQuery_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim startingdate As String = frmSignupReport.SignupDateStart.Text
    Dim endingdate As String = frmSignupReport.SignupDateEnd.Text

    Dim strConnectionString As String = "Data Source=(local)" '; Initial 
Catalog=fitnessCompanyDB.accdb; "
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Memberbase WHERE 
Memberbase.Signupdate = BETWEEN #" & startingdate & "# and #" & endingdate & 
"#")
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    da.Fill(ds, "DataSet1")

    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0))
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "@\SignupReport.rdlc"
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
End Class
```

I understand that it is probably throwing this error because it cannot find the file because it is not named correctly. How do i add the correct file location so it can locate it?

Comment: Use the classes in the [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) that are able to work with an Access Db.  You are using classes in the [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) designed for SQL Server.  Also see: [Access connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

Comment: I did this and it is (starting) to work. Thank you!